# Upload bar shows 100% upload process when the uploading is not done in slow internet connection environment

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest

I am using AWS S3 as the uploading destination and implemented a progress bar. In most cases it worked pretty fine. But with one of our customer whose internet connection is a bit slow (I am not quite sure whether this is the cause or not), the upload shows it is 100 percent completed but actually it wasn't. After waited for several hours, we could finally receive the file in the AWS server.

Below is my code:

```
          if (xhrobj.upload) {                  
              xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {

                  var percent = 0,
                      position = event.loaded || event.position,
                      total = event.total;

                  if (event.lengthComputable) {
                      percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);                          
                      if(percent === 100 && !IsCompletedFired)  
                      {
                        $( document ).trigger( "AmazonStatusUpdateEvent", [ "Completed", nameOfFile, percent, signedFormData ] ); 
                        IsCompletedFired = true;
                      }                                                                                                              

                      else 
                        $( document ).trigger( "AmazonStatusUpdateEvent", [ "Uploading", nameOfFile, percent, signedFormData ] );                              
                  }                      

              }, false);
          }
```

And AmazonStatusUpdateEvent complete is the only event that fires complete functionality for us.

Any clues why this is happening?

Comment: _"After waited for several hours, we could finally receive the file in the AWS server."_ Are you conveying that the `XMLHttpRequest` took several hours to complete?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, I would assume so.

Comment: Not sure how that is possible. What is the `Content-Length` of the file? `XMLHttp.upload` only processes the bytes transmitted, not the bytes received by server

Comment: @guest271314 the file transmitted is around 300 mb.

Comment: I wouldn't use the percentage calculation to decide if the upload has completed. Use the XHR 'load' event instead. Also implement error and abort handlers.

Comment: @jarmod I have taken a read of other posts. It seems they suggest using readyStateChange event. But that doesn't work for me. Do you think load event is better in this case?

Comment: Not sure why a file would take several hours to upload. That does not appear to be possible. Was able to download a 189MB file in seconds at a computer where RAM and disk space was not an issue. Have you asked `amazon-web-services` if in fact the file took several hours to upload?

Comment: @guest271314 it depends on which country and which company you are in.

Comment: If you internet activity is being intercepted or censored, it is perhaps beyond the scope of viewers here at SO to provide a viable solution

Comment: @guest271314 shouldn't be. We are at Australia. Internet connection is a joke here. But I don't think there is any censorship.

Comment: Not sure how you could reproduce upload taking "several hours" to complete? Is dial-up being used for internet connection?

Comment: @guest271314 honestly, I am not quite sure about their environment. But they said it toke hours.

Comment: What occurs when uploading file to a different server?

Comment: Use an event-based solution for 'upload complete', whether it's a load event handler (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or readyStateChange. I'm just saying that percent progress should not be used for this purpose.